# Is there any specification for Decentralized Token Exchange?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, tokens, events

Is the way of doing decentralized token exchange (DEX) on Ethereum blockchain specified in some ERC ?

Exploring event data in Etherscan I found that there are many types of events:

```
  event Order(address tokenBuy, uint256 amountBuy, address tokenSell, uint256 amountSell, uint256 expires, uint256 nonce, address user, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s);
  event Cancel(address tokenBuy, uint256 amountBuy, address tokenSell, uint256 amountSell, uint256 expires, uint256 nonce, address user, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s);
  event Trade(address tokenBuy, uint256 amountBuy, address tokenSell, uint256 amountSell, address get, address give);
  event Deposit(address token, address user, uint256 amount, uint256 balance);
  event Withdraw(address token, address user, uint256 amount, uint256 balance);
```

Are those specified in some ERC ? Do all exchanges have to have these events? What are the methods that all decentralized exchanges share? What is the minimal set of standard methods/events a DEX has to have? Is somebody trying to standarize this? If so, who? Any realated EIP? Are non-fungible tokens out of DEX ?

Those events don't tell me how do I get the list of pending orders, i.e. the tokens available for its sale or purchase. How is this done?

Comment: I don't believe there's any standard.

Comment: I guess there is no any ERC. But we should have.

Comment: We don't need to standardize this. The fact that different token exchanges are in use means that they operate differently in some way. A standard would serve no purpose to anyone.